# Remove Chatter Licences

Tags: chatter

I've been asked whether or not we can remove users from Chatter.

The scenario is that we have leavers who we can't deactivate immediately upon leaving, but who we don't want to appear as a person who can be followed on Chatter, or have any posts seen (some Chatter posts are automated). I can't seem to find any resources on this.

Is there a way to deactivate Chatter licences even if this means creating a 'leavers' profile or something?

Thanks for any ideas on this!

**Edit**
I should clarify we don't have Profile-Based rollout of Chatter enabled although this might be an option worst case. (I think, I can't actually see a way of doing this but this might be because it can only be enabled when it's rolled out?)

**Edit 2** We managed to find [this link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GzQAAA0) to a Salesforce idea for this very problem, released in Winter '15. Presumably the option is there, although it doesn't do a great job of telling you how to enable Profile-Based Chatter rollout.

Comment: Salesforce will have to enable it for you - Per H&T doc: `Salesforce enables the profile-based rollout of Chatter feature for your organization`

Comment: @Eric Good to know, thanks for this. If you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: done............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce will have to enable it for you -

Per H&T doc:

> Salesforce enables the profile-based rollout of Chatter feature for
>   your organization

Here is the link:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_pbr_prepare.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Literally just found and read that same line. Thanks for your input on this.